# Python Add-In Dialog with Textboxes in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, tkinter

With Python Add-In Wizard I created a ButtonTool with which I:

1. click in the map
2. get the coordinates of the mouseclick-location in a dialog with textboxes

I want  to receive the coordinates in a textbox to have the possibility to copy and paste the coordinate values (e.g. to use them  in a document). 
I get a crash between TKinter and arcpy like I read in some posts before. Nevertheless I want to ask, if anybody has experience with this and has a suggestion.

Here is my code:

```
Import Tkinter
class ToolCoord(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE" 
        self.cursor = 3
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
           pt = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x,y))
           main = Tkinter.Tk()
           lb = Tkinter.Label(main, text = "UTM-Koordinaten:")
           lb.pack()
           t1 = Tkinter.Text(main, width=20, height=0)
           t1.insert("end", str(x))
           t1.pack()
           t2 = Tkinter.Text(main, width=20, height=0)
           t2.insert("end", str(y))
           t2.pack()
           main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Write to a temp text file and open it with notepad or write directly to the clipboard.

Comment: @Luke: Thank you for the hint. That was a smart and simple solution. I made it with the Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the hint of Luke I use now a eventbutton with the following code:

```
class ToolClass71(object):
    """Implementation for Python_Addins_addin.tool (Tool)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.shape = "NONE" # Can set to "Line", "Circle" or "Rectangle" for interactive shape drawing and to activate the onLine/Polygon/Circle event sinks.
        self.cursor = 3
    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        pt = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(x,y))
        # set environment
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        mxdpath = mxd.filePath
        df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
        outWorkspace = os.path.dirname(mxdpath)
        # creating a temp feature in the memory space
        tempitem = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory","item","POINT","","DISABLED","DISABLED","Arch_Denkmal_DSch")
        # add and populatin fields with coordinates
        fields = ["x_coords","y_coords"]  
        i = 0  
        for x in fields:  
            arcpy.AddField_management(tempitem, x, "DOUBLE")
            i = i + 1
        arcpy.da.InsertCursor(tempitem, ["SHAPE@XY"]).insertRow([pt])
        out_file = os.path.join(outWorkspace,"Koordinaten.txt")
        value=["x_coords","y_coords"]
        in_table = tempitem
        # export to csv
        arcpy.ExportXYv_stats(in_table,value,"SPACE",out_file,"ADD_FIELD_NAMES")
        # change rows and colums
        with open(out_file) as f:
            lis = [x.split() for x in f]
        with open(out_file, 'wb') as f:
          # Überschreiben der alten Datei mit den neuen Reihen
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(zip(*lis))
            # csv öffnen
        subprocess.call(['C:/Windows/System32/notepad.exe', out_file])
        # delete temp objects and refresh active view
        arcpy.Delete_management("in_memory")
        arcpy.Delete_management("Koordinaten")
        arcpy.Delete_management(out_file)
        arcpy.Delete_management(outWorkspace+"\Koordinaten.xml")
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 2):

Tkinter and Esri Python Addins do not play nice together. You can use Tkinter within scripting with Acrpy, but it will usually crash when implemented in an Addin. [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) GUIs will work within an ESRI Addin. However these will require the end user of your Addin to have wxPython installed on their machine.